# why does laravel's facade behave like a singleton?

Tags: php, laravel

I know that laravel uses facades. but basically I can't wrap my head around it why they use it.  Let's take a look at maybe File facade class. Why did they make the File class as facade when they had already FileSystem class? couldn't we write in our code something like this?

```
$file = new \Illuminate\FileSystem();
$path = $file->get(public_path("test.txt"));
```

but laravel decided to use File facade class after which I can write something like this:

```
$path = File::get(public_path("test.txt"));
```

Where does the beauty reside? if you look at facade pattern, it gives you easier interface to do big jobs and not use 10 lines of code when you can do it with facade in 2 lines, but laravel's facade makes it hard to understand.

Could it be because of they made facade class so that it works like a singleton and this is its amazing side? but then why is singleton amazing ?

I don't understand what's the idea for laravel's facade.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/facades

Comment: It's to make some features swappable, like for example Storage can be file, AWS, dropbox etc.

Answer (score 10):

**Laravel** has a feature similar to **Facade** design pattern, also named **Facades**. This name may confuse you because facades in Laravel don’t fully implement the Facade design pattern. According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/facades)

*Facades provide a “static” interface to classes that are available in the application’s service container.*

So Facade will allow us to use interfaces without worrying the actual implementation behind those.
Lets take an example of Laravel Cache system.
When we call `$items = Cache::get('items:popular');`

Here we retrieve items from cache with the help of Cache facade.

All facade classes are extended from the base **Facade** class. There is only one method, that must be implemented in every facade class: **getFacadeAccessor()** which returns the unique service name inside the IoC container. So it must return a string, that will be resolved then out of the IoC container.

Here is the source code of the **Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache** facade class:

```
<?php 
namespace Illuminate\Support\Facade;
class Cache extends Facade 
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'cache';
    }
}
```

It looks like we are calling a static method `get()` of **Cache** class, but as we have seen there is no such **static** method in **Cache** class. Here method `get()` actually exists in the service inside the container. All the magic is hidden inside the basic **Facade** class.

Inside **Facade** Class we have have `__callStatic()` method. `__callStatic()` is fired every time when a static method that does not exist on a facade is called. So, after calling `Cache::get('items:popular')` we are falling inside this method, we resolve an instance of the service behind a facade out of the IoC container with the help of getFacadeRoot() method. The code for this method is

```
public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
{
    $instance = static::getFacadeRoot();

    if (! $instance) {
        throw new RuntimeException('A facade root has not been set.');
    }

    return $instance->$method(...$args);
}
```

Method `getFacadeRoot()` returns an instance of the service object behind the facade. In this case it eventually points to **CacheManager** Class. Inside the **CacheManager** Class we have a `getDefaultDriver()` method which will get the default cache configuration from `.env` file.

```
public function getDefaultDriver()
{
    return $this->app['config']['cache.default'];
}
```

After getting the default cache configuration, using PHP magic method of `__call()` it attempts to call the `get()` method on **Concrete Class** of default cache (redis, database, memcached etc).

So our original call of `$items = Cache::get('items:popular');` will not change if the default cache changes. Most people use **database** as cache for development and **redis** or **memcached** for backend. It will be **Laravel Facades** job to find out what actions to perform in order to get the value from cache. E.g. the `get()` implementation of **redis** is

```
public function get($key)
{
    $value = $this->connection()->get($this->prefix.$key);

    return ! is_null($value) ? $this->unserialize($value) : null;
}
```

While `get()` implementation for **memacached** is

```
public function get($key)
{
    $value = $this->memcached->get($this->prefix.$key);

    if ($this->memcached->getResultCode() == 0) {
        return $value;
    }
}
```

Similarly you can another cache concrete class. **Laravel** will decide it for you whichever concrete implementation is to be called.