# Why is laravel mainly using Facades instead of singletons?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

when reading here you will see facades are not really facades

[why does laravel's facade behave like a singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53413147/why-does-laravels-facade-behave-like-a-singleton)

all the methods on Facades are static anyway (go look yourself in `Illuminate\Support\Facades`)

and some aliases actually are just that, normal classes for example

`'Arr' => Illuminate\Support\Arr::class,`

whats the point of it being facades?

Comment: You're asking what is the point of facades existing?

Comment: maybe this helps you https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/nusb04/im_confused_are_facades_good_or_bad_now/ quote from there "They are just way of introducing global state into you application hidden under disguise of simplicity."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why is laravel mainly using Facades instead of singletons?

**Facades ARE singletons** because of the way they're implemented.

First, let's define some of the terms we're using:

`Facade` can refer to two things:

1. [Laravel's Facades](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/facades), a tool used for developer convenience and an alternative to dependency injection
2. The [facade design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern). Laravel's Facades are *not* an implementation of the facade design pattern. This is a common point of confusion for those new to Laravel but are familiar with the facade design pattern. Laravel's Facades are better thought of as [static proxies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) to a service within Laravel's container.

`Singleton` is a creational design pattern that lets you ensure that a class has only one instance, while providing a global access point to this instance. ([Source](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/singleton))

These definitions are not mutually exclusive. Something can be a facade *and* a singleton (whether or not they *should* be both is a different conversation).

**Laravel's Facades are singletons in two ways:** the abstract Facade class, and Laravel's IoC Container.

The [abstract `Facade` class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php) - the parent of all individual Facades - is the primary reason Facades act as singletons. When a Facade is called, it resolves its underlying class from Laravel's container and saves it to a local static property. Subsequent calls will refer to the local property value, rather than resolving from the container again.

[Laravel's Inversion of Control Container](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container) is another way that a Facade can reference a singleton object. When you bind a service to the container, you can use [`Container::singleton()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container#binding-a-singleton) to ensure that a service always resolves to the same instance when retrieved.

I hope that clarifies that something can be a singleton *and* a facade simultaneously.

> and some aliases actually are just that, normal classes for example

An alias in this context is just a call to PHP's [`class_alias()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php), and is a way of making Facades and other classes easier to use by minimizing the fully-qualified class name (namespace + class name). Rather than needing to `use Illuminate\Support\Arr;`, you can just `use Arr;` or `\Arr::get()` in your code without the import. This is particularly useful within Blade templates. These aliases are useful for but not limited to Facades.

> if all functions are static, why are the helper functions like `session()` all working with `->` e.g. `config()->set()` vs config()::set()`when the facade does`Config::set()`?

Just a difference in purpose and implementation. A Facade is a proxy - all interaction happens with the Facade itself, but it proxies requests to the underlying service. The helper functions don't proxy any calls, they only return the service retrieved from the container.

```php
// Only interacts with the Facade class.
// set() is proxied via the magic __callStatic() method.
Config::set();

// config() returns an instance of the Config Repository class.
// Subsequent calls are directly on that instance.
// No magic methods used.
config()->set();
```

Facades also come with some mocking and testing utilities that may make them a better solution, depending on your testing needs.

Comment: "and thus it cannot be a singleton" well... the facade has a state namely, following the config example, what config repository it uses. Look at the facade class you will see `    protected static $resolvedInstance;` so facades are stateful just like a singleton. If I recall the explanation was something else, namely that you can test facades better.

Comment: That's a wonderful point, the facades do indeed store their resolved instances. I've revised my answer to use this to emphasize my original point of how both can be simultaneously true.

Comment: bonus: if all functions are static, why are the helper functions like `session()` all working with `->` e.g. `config()->set()` vs `config()::set()` when the facade does `Config::set()` ? like when you were to implement your own little helpful function say `akan()` that gives you access to all the annoying long things you dont want to write out or import, how would you implement it?

Comment: I added that to my answer. TL;DR: similar end functionality (using a service without dependency injection), but different implementations.